# Set Base URL for Preact CLI

Tags: preact

Using Preact CLI is it possible to set the path where the app will be hosted outside of the root directory?

For instance hosting the app at http://mywebsite.com/relativepath/index.html

Answer (score 12):

You have several problems to solve:

**1. Get Webpack to output the correct paths in your html**

This is done via creating a preact.config.js in your root folder, and put the following in there

```
export default (config) => {
  config.output.publicPath = '/relativepath/';
};
```

**2. Set your navigation and assets links in your app**

The best way to solve it in my opinion is to use a global variable which you can be used in your app. So again, edit the preact.config.js to the following:

```
  export default (config, env, helpers) => {
     config.output.publicPath = '/relativepath/';

    // use the public path in your app as 'process.env.PUBLIC_PATH'
    config.plugins.push(
      new helpers.webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.PUBLIC_PATH': JSON.stringify(config.output.publicPath || '/')
      })
    );
  };
```

**3. Routing**

When using your preact app, it should be no problem to navigate. However, if you try to load a fresh URL e.g. www.myserver.com/relativepath/mything/9, the server doesn't know that it should load your single page app living at www.myserver.com/relativepath/index.html

You have two options:

a) Server-side routing

Make sure your all the requests to relativepath (including e.g. relativepath/mything/9) will be rewritten  to your app's relativepath/index.html (in case of using Apache).
Then your Javascript can process the routes, e.g. preact-router

b) Client-side routing (recommended)

The easier option for enabling reloading of URLs is to use hash urls, thereby avoid going through the server when loading a URL.

Your URLs will look something like www.myserver.com/relativepath/#/mything/9 
The server ignores the part after # and only loads (hopefully) /relativepath/index.html

You can use e.g. the preact-router with Hash History to avoid server-side routing, read about it here https://github.com/developit/preact-router#custom-history

Answer (score 0):

I'm proxying from http-proxy-middleware to the preact-cli dev server and these settings worked for me in `preact.config.js`

```
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    config.output.publicPath = '/relativepath';
    config.devServer.devMiddleware.publicPath = "/relativepath";
};
```